# Function that Receives and Rotates Characters in String - Caesar Cipher

Tags: python, function, join, append, caesar-cipher

Earlier we created a function that receives and rotates a single character by "rot" amount:

```
def rotate(letter, rot):
shift = 97 if letter.islower() else 65
return chr((ord(letter) + rot - shift) % 26 + shift)

letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
rot = int(input('Enter a number: '))
print(rotate(letter, rot))
```

Now I need to create a function that rotates all characters in a string by "rot" amount (to the right). So for example

```
encrypt(text, rot)
```

with an input of

```
(Hello World, 1)
```

would return:

```
Ifmmp Xpsme
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
def rotate(letter, rot):
    shift = 97 if letter.islower() else 65
    return chr((ord(letter) + rot - shift) % 26 + shift)

def encrypt(text, rot):
    encrypted = []
    for letter in text:

#use previous rotate function to rotate characters

        encrypted.append(rotate(letter,rot))

        return ''.join(encrypted)

text = input("Enter some text")
rot = int(input("Enter a number"))
print(encrypt(text,rot))
```

But I'm getting a ParseError on line 20: `print(encrypt(text,rot))`. I don't know if I'm using the two functions together correctly - should the rotate function be inside of the encrypt function? Is there another reason why I'm getting the ParseError? Please let me know if I'm on the right track / help if you can. Thank you.

**EDIT**: Indenting `print(encrypt(text,rot))` got rid of the "ParseError: bad input on line 21", but it also gave me a "ParseError: bad input on line 17": `return ''.join(encrypted):` I've tried moving indentation forwards and backwards.

**EDIT 2**: solution looks like this (after fixed indentation):

```
def rotate(letter, rot):
    shift = 97 if letter.islower() else 65
    return chr((ord(letter) + rot - shift) % 26 + shift)

#letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
#rot = int(input('Enter a number: '))
#print(rotate(letter, rot))

def encrypt(text, rot):
    encrypted = []
    for letter in text:

#use previous rotate function to rotate characters

        encrypted.append(rotate(letter,rot))

    return ''.join(encrypted)

text = input("Enter some text")
rot = int(input("Enter a number"))

print(encrypt(text,rot))
```

**EDIT 3**: If you want to maintain spaces and special characters during rotation, you need to specify that the rotate function only runs if the letter is alphabetical, like this:

```
def rotate(letter, rot):
    shift = 97 if letter.islower() else 65
    return chr((ord(letter) + rot - shift) % 26 + shift)

def encrypt(text, rot):
    encrypted = []
    for letter in text:

#if it's a space, keep it a space
#if it's a special character, keep it a special character

        if letter.isalpha():

#use previous rotate function to rotate characters

            encrypted.append(rotate(letter,rot))

        else: 

            encrypted.append(letter)

        return ''.join(encrypted) 

text = input("Enter some text")
rot = int(input("Enter a number"))

print(encrypt(text,rot))
```

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: It's tabbed / spaced in my IDE exactly as it is above. I used tabs to create all spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a dangling colon:

```
    return ''.join(encrypted):
                             ^
```

Delete it.

And by the way, your `return` is inside your for-loop, which will cause the function to exit on the first iteration.

Comment: That got rid of the ParseError. Thank you. Now I'm getting: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Enter a number' on line 20". Question now updated without dangling colon.

Comment: yeah, reverse the order you are applying `intput` and `int` on that string `"Enter a number"... the error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Oh of course. That got rid of that problem. Now I'm getting "NameError: name 'letter' is not defined on line 15"

Comment: ... Well, what do *you* think the problem is? Again, it's **pretty self explanatory**. This isn't a debugging service.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Fixed "for letters in text:" to say "for letter in text:". My problem now is that it's only rotating and outputting the first letter of the string instead of every letter in the string. I.e. (And, 3) just prints "D". So for some reason the for loop isn't iterating / returning every letter in the string - stops after the first one.

Comment: because your `return` is inside your for-loop, so it exists the function on the first iteration. That's the last bug I'm going to fix for you.

Comment: And that solved my problem. Sorry, I didn't know that having the return inside of the for loop caused it to exit on the first iteration. Thanks for your help.